# Smooth Div Scroll jquery not scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, smoothing

The Smooth Div Scroll is great but for some reason the area no longer scrolls when I edit or remove the #makeMeScrollable or #makeMeScrollable div.scrollableArea * 
When I leave it as is it works. Which is a problem for customization.

and it won't work after I take the "*" out of div.scrollableArea *

If I edit the part with the

It's been frustrating figuring out why that part which is supposed to be editable not work at all.

Any help with this jquery would be helpful! Thanks in advance!

```
/* You can alter this CSS in order to give SmoothDivScroll your own look'n'feel */

/* Invisible left hotspot */
div.scrollingHotSpotLeft
{
    /* The hotspots have a minimum width of 75 pixels 
       and if there is room the will grow and occupy 10% 
       of the scrollable area (20% combined). 
       Adjust it to your own taste. */
    min-width: 75px;
    width: 10%;
    height: 100%;
    /* There is a big background image and it's used to 
    solve some problems I experienced in Internet Explorer 6. */
    background-image: url(../images/big_transparent.gif);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 200;
    left: 0;
    /*  The first cursor url is for Firefox and other 
        browsers, the second is for Internet Explorer */
    cursor: url(../images/cursors/cursor_arrow_left.cur), url(images/cursors/cursor_arrow_left.cur),w-resize;
}

/* Visible left hotspot */
div.scrollingHotSpotLeftVisible
{
    background-image: url(../images/arrow_left.gif);                
    background-color: #fff;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    /* Standard CSS3 opacity setting */
    opacity: 0.35; 
    /* Opacity for really old versions of 
       Mozilla Firefox (0.9 or older) */
    -moz-opacity: 0.35;
    /* Opacity for Internet Explorer. */
    filter: alpha(opacity = 35);
    /* Use zoom to Trigger "hasLayout" in 
       Internet Explorer 6 or older versions */ 
    zoom: 1; 
}

/* Invisible right hotspot */
div.scrollingHotSpotRight
{
    min-width: 75px;
    width: 10%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url(../images/big_transparent.gif);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 200;
    right: 0;
    cursor: url(../images/cursors/cursor_arrow_right.cur), url(images/cursors/cursor_arrow_right.cur),e-resize;
}

/* Visible right hotspot */
div.scrollingHotSpotRightVisible
{
    background-image: url(../images/arrow_right.gif);
    background-color: #fff;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    opacity: 0.35;
    filter: alpha(opacity = 35);
    -moz-opacity: 0.35;
    zoom: 1;
}

/* The scroll wrapper is always the same width and 
   height as the containing element (div). Overflow 
   is hidden because you don't want to show all of 
   the scrollable area.
*/
div.scrollWrapper
{
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

div.scrollableArea
{
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
}
#makeMeScrollable
{
width:100%;
height: 330px;
position: relative;
}
#makeMeScrollable div.scrollableArea *
{
position: relative;
float: left;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```

http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/

//^above link to the jquery I am talking about

Answer (score 0):

Is this still a problem or has it been solved?
Since you asked this question version 1.2 has been released and it works a bit differently than version 1.1.

In your question you mention that things stop working when you take out the asterisk in the CSS identifier "div.scrollableArea *". This identifier is just saying "anything/any type of element that is inside the scrollableArea. If you remove it you need to replace it with something more specific. If you have images you use "div.scrollableArea img". If you have div's you use "div.scrollableArea div", if you have linked things you use "div.scrollableArea a" and so on.

The important thing is that the elements that are inside the scrollableArea are displayed in one long line. The method I've used for accomplishing this is to make their **position relative**, **float them left** and set their **display property to block** (needed for the elements to claim their specific horizontal space in the DOM). Apart from that you can set pretty much anything else to your own taste.

Comment: No the problem was never solved as I never knew what exactly to do with the code. And specifically that portion I never understood what would I replace the "*" with. It just was frozen and stuck. If I stripped it into the most basic form it would just scroll but my divs would not appear and it would just scroll and in a buggy way. It would just display images. For my own use of this jquery I used it to scroll my divs and images and lists. It just never worked for me. It was either frozen(not scrolling at all automatically or manually or would scroll weirdly and not how the code was meant to.

Comment: The important thing when it comes to the CSS of the items that are put inside the scrollable area is that they need to claim their layout space (display:block) and they need to be in one long line (float: left). Did you have mixed content in the scrollable area? In that case you either wrap each element in a div and set the CSS selector to "div.scrollableArea div" or you'll need several selectors (one for each element type) "div.scrollableArea div, div.scrollableArea img, div.scrollableArea a" and so on. You mentioned that you had a list in the scrollable area? Was it wrapped in a div?

Comment: Hey thanks for responding! So basically I have all the mix content img, ul, li, divs all wrapped in another div that is within the scrollableArea does that count? Or would I have to wrap each individual item in a it's own div for it to work? The list itself is wrapped in the div main div that wraps inside the div.scrollableArea

Comment: If you want endless looping you have to wrap each piece of content in a div but I think it would be OK to use just one div if you don't want endless looping. The reason you need several div's if you have some form of endless looping is that Smooth Div Scroll will start swapping elements around in a never ending queue. If there's just one element in the queue this won't work.

Comment: Hmmm...so what happens when my whole scrollable area is a list? Would I wrap each li in a div in that case? What about the Ul? I would have to set it to not have endless scrolling in the script or is it just automatically going to not give me that based on the fact that each of my content isn't wrapped in it's own div? Sounds confusing but I really appreciate you taking the time to help me solve this issue. I've been wanting to use this script for so long because I couldn't find anything that worked like this horizontally. It was perfect and fit my idea but I never got it to work, sadly.